# Old sci-fi short story about alien "elixir" and lone astronaut losing sanity?

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading this one in an old sci-fi magazine from the 1970s or early 80s. I'm sort of fuzzy on the details, but this is how it went, as best I can recall:

- A lone astronaut is on board a small space station at the edge of our solar system.  He might be in orbit around one of the gas or ice giant planets. His purpose is to be there when an alien species arrives to deliver some sort of biological substance that has some beneficial effect for mankind.
- The previous astronaut with this duty cracked up, something the current guy refuses to do.
- Late in the story, he realizes that the substance delivered by the aliens has a sinister side effect, and the aliens are actually slowly conquering man as a result.   Unfortunately, the nature of his duty has somehow warped him in the same way as his predecessor.  He tries to write down what he's learned, but it's all alien scribbles that no one would understand.
- In a final act of defiance, the astronaut somehow crashes his station or ship into the alien one.  I think the atmosphere of a gas giant or frozen moon something begins pouring into the station.  The man is going to die, but he believes the aliens will be blamed as an aggressor, and thus save mankind.  Something like that.

Comment: ["Stranger Station"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20%22stranger%20station%22) by Damon Knight.

Comment: That's it - thank you!